# dgrid always showing one record less then present

Tags: dojo, dgrid

I am using dgrid as follows:

```
        query_grid: function(json_query, target, select){
        var self = this;
        require(["dojo/_base/declare", 
                 "dgrid/Grid",
                 "dgrid/extensions/ColumnResizer", 
                 "dgrid/Selection", 
                 "dgrid/selector",
                 "dgrid/extensions/DijitRegistry",
                 "dgrid/extensions/Pagination"], 
            function(declare, Grid, ColumnResizer, Selection, selector, DijitRegistry, Pagination){
                util.destroy("grid_"+json_query.path);
                var columns = {};
                if (select){
                    columns.widget = selector({
                        id: "widget",
                        label: " ",
                        selectorType: "radio", 
                        resizeable: false, 
                        width: 30});
                }
                var data = json_query.data;
                for (var i=0; i<data.keys.length; i++){
                    columns[data.keys[i]] = {label: util.slice_path(data.keys[i], 2)};
                }
                var grid = new (declare([Grid, ColumnResizer, Selection, DijitRegistry, Pagination]))({
                    id: "grid_"+json_query.path,
                    columns: columns,
                    store:  new Memory({data: data.records}),
                    selectionMode: select?"single":"none",
                    pagingLinks: 1,
                    pagingTextBox: true,
                    firstLastArrows: true
                });
                dojo.place(grid.domNode, target, 'last');
                grid.refresh();
            }
        );
        return json_query.path;
    }
```

but when i look at the result, it always shows one record less then is present, until i click on a column header (resulting in a sort), and then all records are shown. Can anyone expain or help with a solution/workaround?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace `grid.refresh()` with `grid.startup()`.

dgrid will automatically call `startup` in cases where an instance is in document flow as soon as it's created.  That's not the case here since you're placing it afterwards, so you need to call `startup` after it's in flow to tell it that it can perform geometry-sensitive operations.

Without calling `startup`, `resize` is never initially called.  As a result, the grid doesn't properly account for the height of the header/footer, and one of your 10 rows is getting obfuscated.  It gets fixed when you sort because `dgrid/Grid`'s `_setSort` method calls `resize` in case the size of the header row changes due to the placement of the sort arrow.

The reason you can replace `refresh` with `startup` in this case is because `startup` calls `refresh` anyway.